# More variables in preg_replace_callback

Tags: php

I need to do the following:

```
$grp = 'something';
$output = preg_replace_callback('/((f|ht)tp)(.*?)(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg)/', function($in){
  return '<a href="'.$in[0].'" class="post-user-img fancybox" '.$grp.'><img src="'.serve_external_image($in[0]).'" alt="" /></a>';
}, $output);
```

However, I cannot pass `$grp` to the `return` part of the code.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `global $grp;` in the function

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. The only way I can get it there is using ``$_SESSION`` and I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `use` in anonymous function declaration

```
function(...) use($grp) { ... }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

ps: It's a php's weird way to create closures :-S